# How can I disable media query in Email Studio/Content Builder?

Tags: email-template, content-builder, email-studio

We are migrating emails from Pardot where emails are fixed to 600px width,
to be compatible on all Clients.

What's the best approach to migrate those?

We want to make the different zones editable, so the client can use them as templates.
We began building these native with the SFMC blocks, but we see that on mobile, images stack up.

Is there a way to disable / override Media queries?

Alternatively, maybe we are missing something and can add editable zones to pasted html code?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When editing the template - go to Code View,

where you'll find (ctrl+f) - look for 'media' - the html code block that begins with

```
<style type="text/css">
      @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
```

You can then delete this block, just make sure to leave the fix for Outlook

i.e. do not delete the following block:

```
<!--[if mso]>
...
```

This should do the trick.